# Paperclip "Data content type is not valid" after trying upload image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

This is what appear in my log:

```
Parameters: {"upload"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x7e20e68
@tempfile=#<Tempfile:C:/Users/bi/AppData/Local/Temp/2/RackMultipart20180116-3004-iw0tdo.jpg>,
@original_filename="Inkedmdb atualizado_LI.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", 
@headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upload\"; 
filename=\"Inkedmdb atualizado_LI.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">,
"ckCsrfToken"=>"AR65EsJdr219Nu21oN1Vlw8fc8XAJTc5ZTIQ1lg9", "CKEditor"=>"pop_objective", 
"CKEditorFuncNum"=>"1", "langCode"=>"pt-br"}

Command :: file -b --mime "C:/Users/bi/AppData/Local/Temp/2/43a60d0ece9425495f704619dc133c4f20180116-3004-bkzljx.jpg"

Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' "C:/Users/bi/AppData/Local/Temp/2/242e48571825b96df1752e5c3933b2fd20180116-3004-1n87xt.jpg[0]" 2>NUL
```

I searched on internet end they suggested me to create a new file in the initializer to overwrite the method spoof or something like that, I created, and now the error changed, but still there.

> Data content type is not valid

Does someone have any ideas, why that happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved, cleaned and precompiled the assets.

```
rails assets:clobber && rails assets:precompile
```